# Pagy : How to keep consistent loop index across pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagy

I get a pg result with a postgres query like

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(distance_sql)
  end
```

And some variables

```
ids = result.column_values(1)
@kms = result.column_values(6)
towns = Town.find(ids)
@pagy, @towns = pagy_array(towns, items: 18)
```

and my loop

```
<% @towns.each_with_index do |town, idx| %>
  <%= town.name %> - <%= @kms[idx] %>
<% end %>
```

How to keep consistent loop index across pages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the loop by :

```
<% @towns.each.with_index(@pagy.offset) do |poi, idx| %>
```